# how to escape stretched-link in html block content

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am developing an app with Django and using bootstrap for the front end.
Do you know how I can a "escape" a stretched-link in bootstrap ?

In fact I like the behavior of having the total card being the link but the problem is that inside the card I have some tag that I want to be as link but it is like my stretched-link is covering all links in the card.

[image]

Below is the snippet from bootstrap adapted to my needs

```
<div class="row gx-5">
    {% for post  in post_list %}
    <div class="col-lg-4 mb-5">
        <div class="card h-100 shadow border-0">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x350/6c757d/343a40" alt="..." />
            <div class="card-body p-4">
                <a class="text-decoration-none link-dark stretched-link" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}"><div class="h5 card-title mb-3">{{post.title}}</div></a>
                <p class="card-text mb-0">{{post.content}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 bg-transparent border-top-0">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-end justify-content-between">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <div class="small">
                            {% for tag in post.tag.all %}
                            <a class="badge bg-secondary text-decoration-none link-light" href="{% url 'blog-index-tag' tag.tag_name %}">{{tag}}</a>
                            {% endfor %}
                            <div class="text-muted">April 2, 2022</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a higher z-index than that of the card and setting the position as relative for the element containing the inner link will make it clickable as [stretched link does not work with elements having position set to relative](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/helpers/stretched-link/#identifying-the-containing-block) and the higher z-index will set the element above the card in the stacking context for the page.

Add the following to set the position and z-index for all the badges inside cards:

```css
.card .badge {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
```